# Table-like graphic including dashed borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

What would be the best approach to create a graphic like this: [image: table-like graphic]

Is there a smarter way than drawing all lines manually with TikZ (maybe matrices)?

Comment: Welcome! What do you have so far? What's the problem? Why do you want it to be a graphic? Ti*k*Z seems overkill but I don't see either being especially troublesome. Draw rectangles or draw lines. Whatever. I don't see really how it could be a matrix as shown, but so long as it makes sense to you. Really, a table would be easiest, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If I am not mistaken the example should be a table with 3 rows and 5 columns. Is it possible to combine multirow and multicolumn to get these kind of cells? And how to create the dashed lines?

Comment: If you provide a Minimum Working Example which demonstrates the kind of content you're working with, it would be possible to say more. Right now, your question isn't really clear as a whole lot depends on the details.

Comment: But `makecell` springs to mind.

Comment: I've had a quick look at it. Unfortunately there is no example showing how to fusion a two cells in a row and another cell in the next row. So I guess I will stick to TikZ. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sure. If you wanted more options, you'd post code people could use to write answers. Since it is impossible to guess what you're doing, if you think it can't be done, there's nothing more to be said. In any case, if you need Ti*k*Z anyway, the overhead to load it isn't an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know the rules for the widths and heights of the boxes. The example with a simple matrix (integer coordinates):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=15mm,
    y=12mm,
    font=\sffamily,
  ]
    \fill[lightgray]
      (2, 3) -- (6, 3) -- (6, 1) -- (3, 1) -- (3, 2) -- (2, 2) -- cycle
    ;
    \draw
      (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (6, 1) -- (6, 0) -- (0, 0) -- (0, 3) --
      (2, 3) -- (2, 2)
      (0, 2) -- (3, 2) -- (3, 1)
    ;
    \draw[densely dashed]
      (2, 3) -- (6, 3) -- (6, 1)
      (4, 3) -- (4, 1)
    ;
    \path
      (0, 2) -- node{\bfseries Level 1} (2, 3)
      (0, 1) -- node{\bfseries Level 2} (3, 2)
      (1, 0) -- node{\bfseries Level 3} (6, 1)
      (2, 2) -- node{\itshape Extra} (4, 3)
      (4, 1) -- node{\itshape This \& That} (6, 3)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with keeping the more or less irregular positions of the vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
  ]
    \def\WD{8cm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\HT}{\WD * 0.4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yunit}{\HT/3}
    \tikzset{
      x=\WD,
      y=\yunit,
    }
    % x positions of the vertical lines as fractions of the image width
    \def\xa{.15}
    \def\xb{.38}
    \def\xc{.57}
    \def\xd{.69}

    \fill[lightgray]
      (\xb, 3) -- (1, 3) -- (1, 1) -- (\xc, 1) -- (\xc, 2) -- (\xb, 2) -- cycle
    ;
    \draw
      (\xa, 0) -- (\xa, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 0) -- (0, 0) -- (0, 3) --
      (\xb, 3) -- (\xb, 2)
      (0, 2) -- (\xc, 2) -- (\xc, 1)
    ;
    \draw[densely dashed]
      (\xb, 3) -- (1, 3) -- (1, 1)
      (\xd, 3) -- (\xd, 1)
    ;
    \path
      (0, 2) -- node{\bfseries Level 1} (\xb, 3)
      (0, 1) -- node{\bfseries Level 2} (\xc, 2)
      (\xa, 0) -- node{\bfseries Level 3} (1, 1)
      (\xb, 2) -- node{\itshape Extra} (\xd, 3)
      (\xd, 1) -- node{\itshape This \& That} (1, 3)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using coordinates seems to be the straight-forward approach :)